Android starting app in phone from watch with RemoteActivityHelper
This is a code example of using RemoteActivityHelper to open play store in connected device (smart watch or mobile) with specific app id, Now I'm sure that the app is installed on the other device and I just want to start it, How I could do it?
val remoteActivityHelper = RemoteActivityHelper(context, executor)

val result = remoteActivityHelper.startRemoteActivity(
    Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        .setData(
            Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.myapp"))
        .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE),
    nodeI


startRemoteActivity supports intents with action set to ACTION_VIEW.
The target app must have an activity that handles "android.intent.action.VIEW":
<activity android:name=".TargetActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="https"
              android:host="www.myaddress.com" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

Then, you can start this activity using:
val remoteActivityHelper = RemoteActivityHelper(context, executor)

val result = remoteActivityHelper.startRemoteActivity(
    Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        .setData(
            Uri.parse("https://www.myaddress.com"))
        .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE),
    nodeId)


Thanks, it worked when I tried to open the mobile app from the watch app but not for the inverse. Do you have any idea what can be the issue?
